# Fresh ubuntu installation not bootable

Tags: boot, grub2

I just tried installing the ubuntu-20.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso on my old Hardware:
One SSD no Dualboot,
Asus Maximus VI Hero,
I7-4770k

However the bios can't seem to find the Grub bootloader. The SSD I installed ubuntu on is being displayed but trying to boo from it ends up in a black screen and return to bios.
In Boot Device Control the UEFI and Legacy OPROM option is selected.

I didn't see any errors during the installation process.

How do I troubleshoot this best?

Comment: I had installed Debian before on the same SSD and I used to boot Windows from an SSD using this hardware

Comment: Try unselecting the Legacy option in BIOS. Try installing the version 22.04.

Comment: Consider running Boot Repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bios update did the trick :)